Injecting custom context in Remix V2 -> Resolving path aliases before running vite
I'm currently trying to inject a custom context into Remix.
The context will work as a dispatcher that will hold command and queries. I want that dispatcher to be available in all of my loaders and actions. I used to do this in V1 inside the main server.js which I would override the getLoadedContext function and call it a day.
I've tried several approaches, and I haven't found the right way to do it.
I'm using Remix Vite with Cloudflare's Wrangler as the target.
Option 1
I tried overriding entry.server.tsx. But it didn't work.
/**
 * By default, Remix will handle generating the HTTP Response for you.
 * You are free to delete this file if you'd like to, but if you ever want it revealed again, you can run `npx remix reveal` ✨
 * For more information, see https://remix.run/file-conventions/entry.server
 */

import type { AppLoadContext, EntryContext } from "@remix-server";
import { RemixServer } from "@remix-run/react";
import { isbot } from "isbot";
import { renderToReadableStream } from "react-dom/server";
import { dispatchWithContext } from "@server/shared/config";

export default async function handleRequest(
  request: Request,
  responseStatusCode: number,
  responseHeaders: Headers,
  remixContext: EntryContext,
  // This is ignored so we can keep it in the template for visibility.  Feel
  // free to delete this parameter in your app if you're not using it!
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
  loadContext: AppLoadContext
) {
  const context = {
    ...remixContext,
    dispatch: dispatchWithContext(),
  };
  const body = await renderToReadableStream(
    <RemixServer context={context} url={request.url} />,
    {
      signal: request.signal,
      onError(error: unknown) {
        // Log streaming rendering errors from inside the shell
        console.error(error);
        responseStatusCode = 500;
      },
    }
  );

  if (isbot(request.headers.get("user-agent") || "")) {
    await body.allReady;
  }

  responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/html");
  return new Response(body, {
    headers: responseHeaders,
    status: responseStatusCode,
  });
}

I think the right one is loadContext but I have no idea how can I override it, since it isn't passed/read anywhere.
Option 2
I then tried passing that custom context to the vite.config.ts.
Unfortunately the custom context has a series of typed aliases (a good chunk of the backend import graph can be obtained from it). As this import occurs inside vite.config.ts, the paths aren't properly resolved.
Here's what I tried:

Running tsconfigPaths in enforce:pre mode in vite.
Using tsconfig-paths programmatically to resolve within the vite.config.ts

import {
  vitePlugin as remix,
  cloudflareDevProxyVitePlugin as remixCloudflareDevProxy,
} from "@remix-run/dev";
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import { lingui } from "@lingui/vite-plugin";
import macrosPlugin from "vite-plugin-babel-macros";
import tailwindcss from "tailwindcss";
import path from "path";

import tsPaths from "tsconfig-paths";

// Load the tsconfig.json file
import tsConfig from "./tsconfig.json";

// Register the paths and baseUrl from tsconfig
const cleanup = tsPaths.register({
  baseUrl: tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl,
  paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
});

import { getLoadContext } from "./load-context";

const config = defineConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@server/*": path.resolve(__dirname, "./app/.server/*"),
      "@server/services/*": path.resolve(__dirname, "./app/.server/services"),
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    {
      ...tsconfigPaths(),
      enforce: "pre",
    },
    remixCloudflareDevProxy({
      getLoadContext,
    }),
    remix(),
    macrosPlugin(),
    lingui(),
  ],
  css: {
    postcss: {
      plugins: [tailwindcss()],
    },
  },
});

cleanup();
export default config;



The getLoadContext:
import { type AppLoadContext } from "@remix-run/cloudflare";
import { type PlatformProxy } from "wrangler";
// Don't use alias paths
import tsPaths from "tsconfig-paths";

// Load the tsconfig.json file
import tsConfig from "./tsconfig.json";

// Register the paths and baseUrl from tsconfig
const cleanup = tsPaths.register({
  baseUrl: tsConfig.compilerOptions.baseUrl,
  paths: tsConfig.compilerOptions.paths,
});

import { dispatchWithContext } from "./app/.server/shared/config";

// When using `wrangler.toml` to configure bindings,
// `wrangler types` will generate types for those bindings
// into the global `Env` interface.
// Need this empty interface so that typechecking passes
// even if no `wrangler.toml` exists.
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-interface
interface Env {}

type Cloudflare = Omit<PlatformProxy<Env>, "dispose">;

declare module "@remix-run/cloudflare" {
  interface AppLoadContext {
    cloudflare: Cloudflare;
    dispatch: ReturnType<typeof dispatchWithContext>;
  }
}

type GetLoadContext = (args: {
  request: Request;
  context: { cloudflare: Cloudflare }; // load context _before_ augmentation
}) => AppLoadContext;

// Shared implementation compatible with Vite, Wrangler, and Cloudflare Pages
export const getLoadContext: GetLoadContext = ({ context }) => {
  return {
    ...context,
    dispatch: dispatchWithContext(),
  };
};
cleanup();

Here's the error:

failed to load config from /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/narrate-flow/vite.config.ts
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package '@server/services' imported from /Users/joseasilis/Documents/programming/narrate-flow/vite.config.ts.timestamp-1712055581793-1f1e467f48f6e.mjs
at packageResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:844:9)
at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:901:20)
at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1121:11)
at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:396:12)
at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:365:25)
at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:240:38)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}

I still haven't found the option.
Alternatives:

Run remix in manual mode, which exposes the node server and I can run tsconfig-paths directly to it. This is a path that I will likely NOT take as it brings many complexities.
Run the getLoadedContext() manually in every request. Which will defeat the purpose of the context.

Another option would be to find a different place in which I can inject the custom context.
Edit x2:
Here's the tsconfig.json
{
  "include": [
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx",
    "**/.server/**/*.ts",
    "**/.server/**/*.tsx",
    "**/.client/**/*.ts",
    "**/.client/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ES2022"],
    "types": ["@remix-run/node", "vite/client"],
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@server/*": ["./app/.server/*"],
      "@atoms/*": ["./app/components/atoms/*"],
      "@molecules/*": ["./app/components/molecules/*"],
      "@organisms/*": ["./app/components/organisms/*"],
      "@templates/*": ["./app/components/templates/*"],
      "@utils/*": ["./app/utils/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./app/types/*"],
      "@remix-server": ["./app/types/remix.ts"],
      "~/*": ["./app/*"]
    },

    "noEmit": true
  }
}

